# SAS adding unwanted spaces to file names when macro variables are included

Tags: sas, text-files, enterprise-guide

I'm creating a text file with SAS and I'm using a macro variable with a date in my text file's name to make it distinct from other similar files.

**The problem I'm experiencing:**

**SAS is adding two unwanted spaces in the middle of the file name.** The unwanted spaces are placed directly before the text generated by my macro variable

I'm certain this has everything to do with my macro variable being used, but on its own, the variable doesn't contain any spaces. Below is my code:

```
proc format;
    picture dateFormat
    other = '%Y%0m%0d%0H%0M' (datatype=datetime);
run;

data _null_;
    dateTime=datetime();
    call symput('dateTime', put(dateTime,dateFormat.));
run;

%LET FILE = text_text_abc_&dateTime..txt;

filename out "/location/here/&FILE" termstr=crlf;

data _null_; set flatfile;
    /*file content is created in here*/
run;
```

The exported file name will look like this:

```
NOTE: The file OUT is:
    Filename=/location/here/text_text_abc_  201702010855.txt
```

If it helps, I'm using SAS E-Guide 7.1.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks, all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign an appropriate default length to your picture format. SAS is applying a default default length of 14 but you need 12, e.g.

```
proc format;
    picture dateFormat (default=12)
    other = '%Y%0m%0d%0H%0M' (datatype=datetime);
run;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for the quick response! I can't accept it for another 4 minutes, according to stack overflow :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `call symputx()` instead of `call symput()`, then SAS will automatically strip the leading and trailing blanks from the value written to the macro variable. You should really only use `call symput()` in the rare cases where you want the macro variable value to have leading or trailing blanks.

Run this little program to see the difference.

```
data _null_;
  str='  XX  ';
  call symput('var1',str);
  call symputX('var2',str);
run;

%put |&var1|;
%put |&var2|;
```